# How do I browse TikTok videos without a proprietary mobile app?

Tags: video, video-streaming, tiktok

I wish to browse TikTok without a mobile app. Is there a web interface available?

It seems that `youtube-dl` somehow can [access the videos without a closed source app](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/blob/master/youtube_dl/extractor/tiktok.py). How do I browse/search the videos?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the time of writing, TikTok now has a web interface that can be accessed through a web browser.

Signup page: https://www.tiktok.com/signup/?lang=en
Following page: https://www.tiktok.com/following?lang=en
Trending / "For you" page: https://www.tiktok.com/trending?lang=en or https://www.tiktok.com/foryou?lang=en
Discover page: https://www.tiktok.com/discover?lang=en

The URL format for a specific user's profile page is: `https://www.tiktok.com/@insert username here`
E.g., the official TikTok account's profile page is at https://www.tiktok.com/@tiktok